# Find number of divisors of N

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

[image]

In this how they have written second equation .

Comment: not clear what you are asking -- please clarify what exactly you seek to understand?

Comment: Are you actually copying questions right from a textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2n+1)^2-(2n-1)^2=8n$, and we have $(2n)^2[(2n+1)^2-(2n-1)^2]=2^5n^3$

Sum of first $n$ cubes is $\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2$.